# How to load images and other elements only on non-HTML5 supporting browsers and use CSS3 code on those who do?

Tags: html, css, browser-detection

I have designed a layout in such a way that I can make most of the images using CSS3 (using gradients, etc) I want to make as much use of HTML5 and CSS3 possible. But I can't ignore the browsers that don't support them yet. So, I was wondering is there a way to detect a browser first and then if it is a non-HTML5/CSS3 supporting browser, the code will load the images and if it is an HTML5/CSS3 supporting browser, it will use advanced code instead. This will save a lot of loading time for them.

What are your views about it? Is this a good approach? How to detect browser before anything else loads on the site?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [HTML5 boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/), it was made to address those issues very toroughly.
Also [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/) can be used to add CSS3 support for IE.
I forgot wether its part of the HTML5 boilerplate or not.

Comment: Ok. Let me check that. Thank for your response.